# Array of Enum values: check for Enum keys with Array.includes?

Tags: typescript

I have the following TypeScript Enum:

```typescript
export enum Brennstoff {
    OEL = "Öl",
    GAS = "Gas",
    SOLAR = "Solar",
}
```

I have a multiselect input of `Brennstoff` that returns an array of the keys:

```
const selected = ["GAS", "SOLAR"]
```

How can I check if the array contains an entry? The following does not work

```
selected.includes(Brennstoff.GAS)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABGAdgVwLYoEJwboDOCMAZuSgN4BQKDKA8gKIAyKAvCgEQBrAGx4AaeowDiAQQDKXXuICGxEWIbSmbSQCU5PaTAEK4KgL61aAYxgkEKYmAFgLCMABM5AbR5TpI3us0tHgBdcysSAzAAOgEYAHMACntHZzcogEt0CwFMVzBiBIIiUgpyKJ8ASgqAbhRgVAQ4TDBLa2JImPikhycXVwysnLyCovQbUqjWNira+pRyBQF7WiA)

Because `Brennstoff.GAS` return `Gas`, so it looks for the value, however I need to look for the key.

How can I do this in TypeScript?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes i meand includes. Your code works because your array contains the enum values, my array contains the enum keys...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for your help! Please check this playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABGAdgVwLYoEJwboDOCMAZuSgN4BQKDKA8gKIAyKAvCgEQBrAGx4AaeowDiAQQDKXXuICGxEWIbSmbSQCU5PaTAEK4KgL61aAYxgkEKYmAFgLCMABM5AbR5TpI3us0tHgBdcysSAzAAOgEYAHMACntHZzcogEt0CwFMVzBiBIIiUgpyKJ8ASgqAbhRgVAQ4TDBLa2JImPikhycXVwysnLyCovQbUqjWNira+pRyBQF7WiA.   As you can see, both console statements are false, because the array contains enum keys, but the includes key checks vor enum values...

Comment: Well just do `selected.includes("GAS")`. If you also add a type annotation to `selected` like `const selected: (keyof typeof Brennstoff)[] = ["GAS", "SOLAR"]`, then in case you rename `BrennStoff.GAS` to something else, typescript will throw an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Introduction & TL;DR

Two solutions for you, both of which rely on a small bit of setup we'll go into below:

1. Using a stricter type for `selected` so it can only contain valid `Brennstoff` keys, it looks like:

   ```typescript
   console.log(selected.some(key => Brennstoff[key] === Brennstoff.GAS)); // true
   console.log(selected.some(key => Brennstoff[key] === Brennstoff.OEL)); // false
   ```
2. Keeping `selected` as a `string[]`, it looks like:

   ```typescript
   console.log(selected.some(key => isBrennstoffKey(key) && Brennstoff[key] === Brennstoff.GAS)); // true
   console.log(selected.some(key => isBrennstoffKey(key) && Brennstoff[key] === Brennstoff.OEL)); // false
   ```

#### Validating keys

Both solutions involve validating that a string is a valid `Brennstoff` key, so let's look at that first:

You can use a type assertion function to validate keys. The type of a `Brennstoff` key is `keyof typeof Brennstoff`, but you may find it useful to have an alias for that:

```typescript
type BrennstoffKey = keyof typeof Brennstoff;
```

Then the assertion function looks something like this:

```typescript
const BrennstoffKeys = new Set(Object.keys(Brennstoff));
function assertBrennstoffKey(key: string): asserts key is BrennstoffKey {
    if (!BrennstoffKeys.has(key)) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid Brennstoff key "${key}"`);
    }
}
```

(You don't have to use the `Set`, you could call `Object.keys` every time you want to do the validation.)

I've taken the liberty of assuming each value has only one key.

I find I often want the type guard version as well as the assertion version; that combination would be something like:

```typescript
const BrennstoffKeys = new Set(Object.keys(Brennstoff));
function isBrennstoffKey(key: string): key is BrennstoffKey {
    return BrennstoffKeys.has(key);
}
function assertBrennstoffKey(key: string): asserts key is BrennstoffKey {
    if (!isBrennstoffKey(key)) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid Brennstoff key "${key}"`);
    }
}
```

With that in place, let's look at two approaches...

#### Using a stricter type for `selected`

If `selected` is going to contain the *key names* from `Brennstoff`, then I suggest declaring it that way — `BrennstoffKey[]`:

```typescript
const selected: BrennstoffKey[] = [];
```

Then you validate the strings before adding them:

```
let key: string = /*...*/;
assertBrennstoffKey(key);
selected.push(key);
```

To check if it has the key, since since the type of `selected` is strict enough, we can use `some` to see if it has the key for a particular value in it:

```typescript
console.log(selected.some(key => Brennstoff[key] === Brennstoff.GAS)); // true
console.log(selected.some(key => Brennstoff[key] === Brennstoff.OEL)); // false
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

#### With `selected` being `string[]`

If you want to keep `selected` as a `string[]`, then we apply validation when doing the check instead:

If you're happy to do some up-front preparation (perhaps just after defining `Brennstoff`), it's fairly straightforward:

```typescript
console.log(selected.some(key => isBrennstoffKey(key) && Brennstoff[key] === Brennstoff.GAS)); // true
console.log(selected.some(key => isBrennstoffKey(key) && Brennstoff[key] === Brennstoff.OEL)); // false
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-PLMqsNjhyOoci055AA)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation, this was very helpful and clears up a lot of thing!